# Why DATEDIFF() in mysql is not working properly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two field, which startDate and endDate,which is in varchar. I have to convert them to date and then I have to get the difference between them.

When I am querying to convert the date, it works.

The query is:

```
 select str_to_date(NewCrgs.PollDefination.endDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as
 endd, str_to_date(NewCrgs.PollDefination.startDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as
 startt FROM NewCrgs.PollDefination;
```

[image: date converting result]

But when I am trying to get date difference,it shows nothing. why?

The query is:

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF((str_to_date(NewCrgs.PollDefination.endDate,
 '%d/%m/%Y')),(str_to_date(NewCrgs.PollDefination.startDate,
 '%d/%m/%Y')));
```

Comment: A sidenote: You should not store dates as varchar. Is there any reason why you dont store them as dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to modified it in this way.

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF (
        str_to_date(NewCrgs.PollDefination.endDate, '%d/%m/%Y'),
        str_to_date(NewCrgs.PollDefination.startDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    ) AS datedifference 
FROM 
    NewCrgs.PollDefination;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF (
        NewCrgs.PollDefination.endDate,
        NewCrgs.PollDefination.startDate
    ) AS datedifference 
FROM 
    NewCrgs.PollDefination;
```

Note the 'AS' at the end.

PS. I'm note sure if you need to convert the varchars to dates. [This example](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp) uses strings as well.

Comment: it is not working :( . I have followed this example.